# Region server fails in cloudera after phoenix-4.3.0-server.jar is added

Tags: hadoop, hbase, cloudera, apache-phoenix

I have added the `phoenix-4.3.0-server.jar` in the `/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hbase/lib` of the cloudera.

When I tried to start the servers(Region and master servers), only the master server is started. The region server sometimes starts momentarily and goes down immediately.

This worked fine with the previous version of the phoenix(4.0.0-incubating).

Kindly help me with a workaround  for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it failed when upgrading from 4.0.0 to 4.3.0 was the compatibility. For some reason 4.3.0 was not compatible to be upgraded from an older version of phoenix.

So, upgrading from 4.0.0 to 4.1.0, restarting the HBase server and then  upgrading from 4.1.0 to 4.3.0 with a HBase restart helped the situation.